# Convert a string of time value to Datetime object

Tags: vb.net, string, .net-3.5, type-conversion, datetime-format

I have a gridview loaded with some rows of data having string having time value (like '10:30 PM'). When i try to insert all grid data to database using foreach loop considering each row in grid, i would like to insert string having time value as datetime varaible in SQL database. So i tried to convert the string as

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells(4).Value)
```

But it arise a format exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any idea to convert this string to datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date/Time types admit different formats and thus you have to add some additional information in order to allow VB.NET to know what you mean exactly. Sample (right/wrong) alternatives:

```
Dim test1 As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("1-13-2000", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")) 'OK
Dim test2 As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("1-13-2000", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")) 'Error
Dim test3 As Date = Date.ParseExact("10:30 pm", "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 'OK
Dim test4 As Date = Date.ParseExact("9:30 pm", "hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 'ERROR
```

`Convert.ToDateTime` takes into account the format of the corresponding `CultureInfo`; if you don't specify anything it assumes that you want to use the default one in the given computer. Best thing is always specifying the culture you want. Other alternative you have is telling the exact format, via for example `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your value might be an empty string.

Put a condition

```
if(row.Cells(4).Value <> null AND row.Cells(4).Value <> string.Empty)
    Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells(4).Value)
```